# Canvas – createRadialGradient() not working as expected in Chrome v65

Tags: javascript, canvas, webkit, radial-gradients

When using `context.createRadialGradient()` on a 2d `context`, the gradient is not rendering as expected in [Chrome v65](https://d2ffutrenqvap3.cloudfront.net/items/2o2c2j3M0z2R2H381y2E/Screen%20Shot%202018-04-03%20at%205.07.49%20PM.png).

[image: Screen shot]

The [example above is from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createRadialGradient), but it's also happening in [some of my own code](http://nature-of-code.ljd.dk/experiments/koa-dust-motes/).

The gradient works fine in [Firefox v59](https://d2ffutrenqvap3.cloudfront.net/items/2T1E350h410L2U1i0c37/Screen%20Shot%202018-04-03%20at%205.08.55%20PM.png), Safari v11. It fails in Opera v52, so maybe it's a new bug in webkit? I've tested this on two different computers, so shouldn't be anything in my local setup causing it.

Anybody else experiencing this bug or better yet know how to fix it?

**EDIT: Found [an open issue on Chromium here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=826619&q=component%3ABlink%3ECanvas%20&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).**
Apparently this is not a consistent bug, and should be fixed in v66 if I'm reading the comments correctly.

Comment: Works on Android version and on my non retina macOs. But anyway, the code on MDN page should work just fine, so check iglf there is an existing bug report on chromium's issue tracker, and if not, open one specifying your specs.

Comment: I found an open [Chromium Issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=826619&q=component%3ABlink%3ECanvas%20&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified). It's apparently not a totally consistent bug, and should be fixed in v66. It's happening for me in both my normal Chrome, incognito Chrome and Opera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the post above, there's an [issue in Chromium v65](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=826619&q=component%3ABlink%3ECanvas%20&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified). It should all be fixed in v66.

If you do need to fix it right now, the hacky way is to make sure that the gradient doesn't receive identical `x` and `y` arguments for the first and the second circle:

```
var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(100,100,100,100,100,0); // Doesn't work
var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(100,100,100,100.001,100,0); // Works
```

You can see the [fix in effect here](http://l.ljd.dk/1L). Happy hacking!